# Issue with Javascript closure

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code:

```
var blah = function(x, y){
    var e = {
       ox: x, 
       oy: y,
       etc.
    }
    return e;
};
```

However, I am getting an error "x is undefined". I thought that x and y should be available in inner scopes. Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/4mYbn/1/

Comment: Where are you receiving the error? It's not when this code is ran, is it?

Comment: The arguments are indeed available in all inner scopes within the function, could you post a non-working example?

Comment: post the code that calls blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Did you use `new` and did you pass 2 params?

```
var blah = function(x, y){
    var e = {
       ox: x, 
       oy: y
    }
    return e;
};

z = new blah(1,2);
z.ox // 1
z.oy // 2
```

Comment: "new" is not required here.   The jsfiddle that Jamas Allardice offers shows it working without new.